# Returning node pointer using a template

Tags: c++, templates

Trying to search for a specific Node in a Tree, and I need to return a pointer to the Node when I've found it. The nodes are of a derived class type called `BudgetEnvelope`, and the error that I'm getting reads:

> Cannot initialize return object of type `BudgetEnvelope` with an lvalue of type `Node<BudgetEnvelope>`

```
template <class T>
T* Tree<T>::find( Node<T> * ptr, T value){
    if(ptr != NULL){
        if(ptr->value == value){
            return ptr;    <------error is on this line
        }
        else{
            if(value < ptr->value){
                return find(ptr->left, value);
            }
            else{
                return find(ptr->right, value);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

My understanding was that since the nodes are of the same type as the pointer that I am returning, that it should work. How can I resolve this?

Edit: More information.
When I change the return type to `Node<T>*`, the file where I am using this method gives me another error.

```
void EnvelopeBox::deposit(int id, double amount){
    BudgetEnvelope searchKey = *new BudgetEnvelope(id, "searchKey");
    BudgetEnvelope* keyPtr = envelopes.find(searchKey);     <----same error
    keyPtr->deposit(amount); 
}
```

The `deposit` method is defined inside the `BudgetEnvelope` class, not `Node`, so if I change `keyPtr` to be the same type `Node<T>*`, I can't access the `deposit` method.

Comment: Is the class `Node` defined within the class `Tree`? (As fast as the answer goes, you should be returning a pointer to `Node<T>`, not a pointer to `T`.)

Comment: What is the type of envelopes ?

Comment: envelopes is the Tree I am searching.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to return `Node<T>*` not `T*` because `ptr` is of type `Node<T>*`

e.g.

```
Node<T>* Tree<T>::find( Node<T> * ptr, T value)
```

**EDIT:**

With the new information you provided, what you need to do is convert

```
BudgetEnvelope* keyPtr = envelopes.find(searchKey);
```

to

```
Node<BudgetEnvelope>* keyPtr = envelopes.find(searchKey);
```

then to access the data inside, you do the following:

```
BudgetEnvelope myValue = keyPtr->Value;
myValue.deposit(amount)
```

What you need to do is access the data inside the node.
Alternatively, you can return `ptr->Value` from your `find` function.

Comment: I did try that, but then it gave me an error in a different file. I'll edit my post to show what happens then.

Comment: I`ve updated my answer based on your new information.

Answer (score 2):

`ptr` is a pointer to type `Node<T>` and the function returns a pointer to type `T`. Types `T` and `Node<T>` are different.

If you want to return a `T*` you should return whatever method in your `Node` class returns a pointer to the value contained in that `Node`. Otherwise, which i think is what you want, change the signature of `T* Tree<T>::find( Node<T> * ptr, T value)` to return `Node<T>*`, as Justin suggested.